# Grails error with href

Tags: grails

I need some help with this:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="listExamples"> 
    ${message(code: 'examples.label', default: 'example')} 
</a>
```

Normally I go to:

```
"aplication/controller/listExamples"
```

But when I click it, results is:

> 'The requested resource (/aplication/controler/listExample) is not available.'

Why does that happen? First at all, I did not use a link for `listExample`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the g:link tag, for example:

```
<g:link controller="aplication" action="listExamples" class="btn btn-default">
    <g:message code='examples.label' default='example'/> 
</g:link>
```